# Nutch crawler not scaling for large urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to set up a nutch crawler on an Amazon EMR cluster with two master nodes, scalable. My seed url list is only 10000 urls, but my crawler gets stuck on fetch phase in Map-reduce job at around 90 percent. It ran fine for 5000 urls. Is there any configuration that I might be missing?

Comment: and share your error logs  !!

Answer (score 0):

Go the MapReduce UI and check the logs for the Fetch phase. They probably contain a clue as to what went wrong.